# Dynamic Form with generated names

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Hey y'all I'm trying to build a form that generates fieldsets and inputs where all the inputs in a fieldset will have the same number as a suffix so that I can use them for equations. Ideally you'd fill in the available inputs then click "Add Another Fence" and an identical section of the form would appear with inputs listed as "fenceDescription2", "postQuantity2" etc and then if you did it again they would read "fenceDescription3", "postQuantity3" etc. Here is my fiddle of what I have attempted so far - http://jsfiddle.net/gv0029/3dnNP/1/ - if anyone can point out where I went wrong I would appreciate it greatly, thank you so much. And here is the code as well
HTML:

```
<fieldset id="fence">
    <div id="inputFence1" class="clonedInputFence">
        <fieldset id="fenceDescripton">
            <legend><strong>Fence Description</strong>

            </legend>Fence Description:
            <select name="fenceHeight" id="fenceHeight">
                <option value="select">Select Fence Height</option>
                <option value="6" id="fH6">6 Ft.</option>
                <option value="8" id="fH8">8 Ft.</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset id="post">
            <legend><strong>Post Type</strong>

            </legend>

            <label>Post Quantity:
                <input type="postQuantity" name="postQuantity" id="postQuantity" value="" />
            </label>
            <select name="postMeasurements" id="postMeasurements">
                <option value="select">Select Post Measurements</option>
                <option value="23/8 x .065 x 8" id="23/8 x .065 x 8">2 3/8 x .065 x 8</option>
                <option value="23/8 x .095 x 8" id="23/8 x .095 x 8">23/8 x .095 x 8</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>

    </div>
</fieldset>
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="btnAddFence" value="Add Another Fence" />
        <input type="button" id="btnDelFence" value="Remove Fence" />
    </div>
```

JS:

```
//Dynamic Fence Input Fields
    $('#btnAddFence').click(function() {
                var num     = $('.clonedInputFence').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
                var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);      // the numeric ID of the new input field being added

                // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
                var newElem = $('#inputFence' + num).clone().attr('id', 'inputFence' + newNum);

                //Fieldset creation
                newElem.find('fieldset').attr('id', 'name' + newNum);

                //Fence Description 
                newElem.find($("select[name=fenceHeight]")).attr('id', 'fenceHeight' + newNum).attr('name', 'fenceHeight' + newNum);


                //Post Type
                newElem.find($(':input[name="postQuantity"]')).attr('id', 'postQuantity' + newNum).attr('name', 'postQuantity' + newNum);
                newElem.find($("select[name=postMeasurements]")).attr('id', 'postMeasurements' + newNum).attr('name', 'postMeasurements' + newNum);



                // insert the new element after the last "duplicable" input field
                $('#inputFence' + num).after(newElem);

                // enable the "remove" button

                $('#btnDelFence').removeAttr('disabled');

                // business rule: you can only add 5 names
                //if (newNum == 5)
                    //$('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','disabled');
            });

            $('#btnDelFence').click(function() {
                var num = $('.clonedInputFence').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
                $('#inputFence' + num).remove();     // remove the last element

                // enable the "add" button
                //$('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','');
                $('#btnAddFence').removeAttr('disabled');

                // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
                if (num-1 == 1)
                    $('#btnDelFence').attr('disabled','disabled');
            });

            $('#btnDelFence').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Comment: This appears to be working. What is the question for this?

Comment: Well right now it just says "name" for every fieldset. I can't figure out how to have it look at the original name then just add "newNum" as a prefix so that, for example, the second "post" fieldset would have an id of "post2". Also the inputs in the cloned fieldsets still have the original names. For example the second "postQuantity" input still has an id of "postQuantity" instead of "postQuantity2".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bypass this whole thing by naming your inputs "fenceDescription[]" instead of "fenceDescription1", "fenceDescription2", etc.  Then "fenceDescription" will be an array of values when you're looking at your POST data (I assume you're using POST) later on.

Then all you have to do is duplicate the fieldset and not worry about anything other than perhaps clearing the inputs of the cloned version.

By the way, you also might be experiencing problems because you're using ID incorrectly.  Only one thing on a page should ever have a certain ID.  If something has, or could have, multiple of the same IDs you should use "class" instead.

If you must have different input names you would want to do something like this:

Name your select like this:

```
<select name="fenceHeight_1" class="fenceHeight">
```

Again, very important to notice I've changed fenceHeight to be a class instead of an ID.

Then after you've made your clone you will have two inputs named "fenceHeight_1".  So you can then alter the number at the end by doing this

```
//get the input name and split into array (assuming your clone is always last)
var parts=$('.fenceHeight:last').attr('name').split("_");
//change the second element of the array to be one higher
parts[1]++;
//join back into a string and apply to the new element
$('.fenceHeight:last').attr('name',parts.join("_"));
```

See this fully working jsfiddle.  Note the changes and comments to the HTML too!
http://jsfiddle.net/3dnNP/4/

Comment: My main concern is being able to plug in the inputs to equations that will be used in JS and JQuery and should automatically update as it is filled in. I don't have the entire form here because that would be very long but I am trying to use the info the user puts in to fill out other sections of the form.

Comment: @gv0029 See my changes to answer

Comment: @gv0029 I'm incredibly bored/procrastinating and made a bunch of changes to the jsfiddle.  See the update to the answer!